# Running Angular 2 on Ubuntu Server - Blank Screen No Errors

Tags: php, angular, ubuntu

I have an angular 2 project, when I run on my locally via XAMPP it works fine, but when I add Angular 2 to my Ubuntu Server, I get a blank white screen with no errors. I add an .htaccess file and it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also enabled Apache's mod_rewrite extension and adjusted my VirtualHosts in /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf file so it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front/src
    <Directory /var/www/html/front>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    Alias /api  /var/www/html/api/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/api>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But all I get is a blank screen with no errors on the page.

I am running Angular CLI: 1.6.2, node v8.11.3, npm 6.3.0

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Check the browser console? `/var/www/html/front/src` Did you build your project and place the contents of dist here?

Comment: Nothing in browser console. My index file is in src folder

Comment: Yes, it is, but did you `build` your project?  I don't think simply pointing to the index will work, especially if you are using apache.

Comment: Okay, I will try to build in my src folder......ng serve correct?

Comment: No. Not at all. I'd say take a look at the docs https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: I just did an ng build in src....still blank

Comment: no console errors

Comment: You didn't read the documentation. Your application compiles in the `dist` directory.

Comment: I don't have a dist directory in my project, this is an existing project I inherited

Comment: Weird...my dist folder is one level up from src (src and dist are in the same folder)

Comment: set your document root to dist

Comment: I changed it to this: DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front/dist instead of DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front/src, now instead of a blank page it takes me to a page with a list of folders and files...in this case one folder

Comment: Holy shit, I changed it to dist/browser and it worked! Thanks

Comment: if you put it into an answer I will accept it

Comment: @Kisaragi Actually there is one thing wrong, I am able to navigate through the pages and the url changes, but if I refresh the page, I get a 404 error, how come?

Comment: Your rewrite rules are incorrect most likely.

Comment: Suggestion on how to fix it?